# Accounting for newline characters in javascript on Windows and *nix systems

Tags: javascript

Below is the `Addon` code which saves text to file.
This works perfectly on `*nix` systems.

The code grabs the current selected text from UI (which may contain `newline` characters) and saves this string to a file.
The problem is that on `Windows`, no `newline` characters are preserved when text file is opened in `Notepad`.
I understand `\r\n` is the correct carriage return on `Windows` but how can I support both `Windows` and `*nix` systems without having to parse/replace the user's selected string?

```
var {Cc,Ci,Cu,components} = require("chrome"),
    ContextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");

Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");

var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile),
    ostream,
    string;

file.initWithPath('C:\Users\rob');
file.append('Test.txt');

try{        

    if (file.exists() === false) {file.create(Ci.nsIFile.NORMAL_FILE_TYPE, 420);}

        ostream = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file, FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY | FileUtils.MODE_CREATE | FileUtils.MODE_TRUNCATE);

        var converter = Cc["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].createInstance(Ci.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
        converter.charset = "UTF-8";

        string += 'First' + '\n\n';
        string += 'Second' + '\n\n';

        var istream = converter.convertToInputStream(string + ContextMenu.SelectionContext());

        NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(status) {

            if (!components.isSuccessCode(status)) {

                alert('failure');

            }else{

                alert('success');
            }
        });

    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the result on `Windows`:

[image]

And this is the result on `Linux`:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6833299/1189040) ?

Comment: \r?\n will match a single newline or a newline preceded by a return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with this in the end ..

```
if (System.getPlatform().indexOf('win') >= 0){
    var combinedString = string + ContextMenu.SelectionContext();
    combinedString = combinedString.replace(/[\n]/g, '\r\n');
}
```